# Generating legend from sld

Tags: geotools, svg

I have and SLD with following rule

```
<se:Rule>
      <se:Name>Primary Pole</se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title>Primary Pole</se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>type1</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PointSymbolizer>
        <se:Graphic>            
          <se:ExternalGraphic>
            <se:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="svgs/type1.svg"/>
            <se:Format>image/svg+xml</se:Format>
          </se:ExternalGraphic>             
          <se:Size>16</se:Size>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:PointSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
```

and for creating the base64 representation of this rule i am using below code

```
 // assuming we  will provide only point
 BufferedImage image = null;
 image = Glyph.point(rule);
 ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 ImageIO.write(image, "png", bos);
 Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
 String imageString = encoder.encodeToString(bos.toByteArray());
```

but issue is the when i show it on client when height and width is 16 image is displayed fine but when i increase the height and width  the  generated base64 image is blured (pixelated)  what i think its generated the image w.r.t the size in rule is there any option to ignore it and provide my own size? Or is there a better way to generate the legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually much harder than it looks - see GeoServer's [`BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder`](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/wms/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wms/legendgraphic/BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.java) class for the full gory detail. The key step seems to be the method [`calcSymbolSize`](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/wms/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wms/legendgraphic/BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.java#L545):

```
    private double[] calcSymbolSize(
        double defaultMaxSize,
        double defaultMinSize,
        FeatureType featureType,
        Feature feature,
        final Rule[] rules) {
    // check for max and min size in rendered symbols
    double minSize = defaultMaxSize;
    double maxSize = defaultMinSize;

    final int ruleCount = rules.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < ruleCount; i++) {
        Feature sample = getSampleFeatureForRule(featureType, feature, rules[i]);
        MetaBufferEstimator estimator = new MetaBufferEstimator(sample);
        final Symbolizer[] symbolizers = rules[i].getSymbolizers();
        for (int sIdx = 0; sIdx < symbolizers.length; sIdx++) {
            final Symbolizer symbolizer = symbolizers[sIdx];
            if (symbolizer instanceof PointSymbolizer || symbolizer instanceof LineSymbolizer) {
                double size = getSymbolizerSize(estimator, symbolizer, defaultMaxSize);
                // a line symbolizer is depicted as a line of the requested size, so don't go
                // below min
                if (size < minSize && !(symbolizer instanceof LineSymbolizer)) {
                    minSize = size;
                }
                if (size > maxSize) {
                    maxSize = size;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return new double[] {minSize, maxSize};
}
```

Comment: is there any method available to see which sld rules are applied ?

Comment: I think that would be [LegendUtils.getApplicableRules](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/wms/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wms/legendgraphic/LegendUtils.java#L555)